More than 6 or 7 connection for single nodejs server with mysql
I'm using Node.js, MySQL, and ReactJS in my web app. Using the Node.js library 'mysql' and a connection pool, when I run my frontend project, it shows about 5 to 6 connections in the database (running the command SHOW PROCESSLIST). Is it normal to have that many connections, or should there only be one connection?
If multiple connections are normal, then why are they not closing when I don't need them? It can have only one idle connection to prevent expensive reconnections to the database, but why are multiple connections idle and not closing?
I have used a connection pool, so it should automatically release the connection. When I used events like:
It showed that the connection is released, but it still appears in the database in "SLEEP" mode when I run the SHOW PROCESSLIST command.
pool.on('release', function (connection) {
  console.log('Connection %d released', connection.threadId);
});

const dbConfig = {
  timezone: "+05:30",
  host: "host",
  user: "user",
  password: "pwd",
  database: "db_name",
  port: 3306,
  connectionLimit: 30,
  multipleStatements: true,
  acquireTimeout: 10000, 
  idleTimeout: 3000,  
  waitForConnections: true, 
};


function query(sql, args, writeLog) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
      if (err) {
        console.trace(err);
        return reject(err);
      }
      try {
        conn.query('SET SESSION wait_timeout = 120', (err) => {
          console.log("wait timeout");
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error setting session wait_timeout:', err);
          }
        });

        conn.query('SET SESSION interactive_timeout = 120', (err) => {
          console.log("interactive_timeout");
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error setting session interactive_timeout:', err);
          }
        });

        conn.query(sql, args, (err1, rows) => {
          if (err1) {
            console.trace(err1);
            return reject(err1); 
          }
          if (writeLog) {
            writeLog(sql, args);
          }
          resolve(rows);
        });
      } finally {
        conn.release();
      }
    });
  });
}


app.get(
  "/route",
  checkToken,
  (req, res) => {
    const query =
      mysqlParams(queryString, {
        companyId: req.body?.userDetails?.company_id || 0,
      });

    queryEngine.query(query, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({ rows, fields });
      }
    });
  }
);

